# VS 2017 Cannot deploy SSIS SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

Running Visual Studio 2017 with latest patches and SQL Server Data Tools installed. Created a new Integration Services project, target server version is SQL Server 2012. Added an existing SSIS package from a SQL Server 2012, made a small edit a task, and saved. When I try to deploy via package model, I get this error:

> Storing or modifying packages in SQL Server requires the SSIS runtime and database to be the same version. Storing packages in earlier versions is not supported.

Since both the project and target server are both SQL Server 2012, I'm stumped on where the version discrepancy lies.

Previously I was able to download, edit, and re-save the package in VS 2010, so it seems to be something particular to Visual Studio 2017. Any ideas?

Edit: I also tried creating a new package in the project with *nothing* in it and it has the same error, so it's definitely something with VS 2017 and not code related.

Answer (score 3):

In the property pages for an Integration Services project, on the General tab of Configuration Properties, select the TargetServerVersion property and choose SQL SQL Server 2012 and deploy it.

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear in the original post, it already has a TargetServerVersion property of SQL 2012. 

"Since both the project and target server are both SQL Server 2012, I'm stumped on where the version discrepancy lies."